# Accessing a Ruby Variable from Inside of an HTML class and Using it In a JS Function

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, variables, tooltip

I'm trying to access the ruby "variablename" variable from my HTML:

```
<% array.each_with_index do |variablename, i| %>
<span class="classname">
    <a ng-href="/variablename/<%= variablename.gsub(' ', '').strip %>"> <%=variablename.strip %> </a>
</span>
```

in a JS tooltip constructor:

```
$('.classname').ready(function(element) {
    Tooltipconstructor.create('.classname', {
      ajax: {
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: /api/etc/{} // Where I want to access the HTML/Ruby Variable
     etc..........
```

How can I access this variable? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using angular? Is that tooltip in a directive?

Comment: Using angular, and it's not in a directive.

Comment: Well, you can use a directive and pass the variable name as a value of an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get the value from the `a` text:

```
$('.classname').ready(function(element) {
  var path = $('.classname > a').text()
  Tooltipconstructor.create('.classname', {
    ajax: {
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      url: /api/etc/+path // Where I want to access the HTML/Ruby Variable
   etc..........
```

Comment: The problem is that I am dealing with an array, where each index of the array has a different value for "variablename". When I use the path solution,  it stores as a variable every item in the array, and not just the one I wish to access. The one I want to access and use, however, will change based on which object the user hovers over.

Comment: Best solution is to use the directive here.